# Sprout Email - output the

Tags: plugin-sproutemail, author

I've got a notification set up when a user is saved/updated.

I'm trying to add the author/user who made the update

Tried the following to see what returns and nothing:

```
{author}

{author.email}

{author.firstName}

{{object.author.email}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic object passed to a Notification Event depends on which Event is being triggered. In your case, the "When a user is saved" event has access to the [User Model](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-user.html).

All of the attributes you are trying to access are on that User Model and are directly associated with the model itself:

```
{firstName}
{lastName}
{email}

{{ object.firstName }}
{{ object.LastName }}
{{ object.email }}
```

In your example, you are trying to access the attribute `author`. However, `author` is an attribute from the [Entry Model](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html#property-author). The Entry Model is available to the "When an entry is saved" event and other Entry-specific events.

Comment: Ok thank you.

Additional question. Will the notification only work when the entry is saved/updated as a live/enabled entry?